# Axios PUT Data with Params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, post, axios, expo

My backend API route is `/api/updateUser/:id`
How am I supposed to POST data into this API? I'm familiar with POST request for non params APIs but this one has an `/:id` in the route.

Can someone show me an example with this demo code

```
state = {
    username: "random123",
    password: "random123",
    userid: "qwertyuiop",
  };


saveDetails = async () => {
    const { username, password, userid } = this.state;
    let data = new FormData();
      data.append('username',username);
      data.append('password',password);
    axios
      .put(apiEndPoint+'?id='+this.state.userid, data) //this is where I need help
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          console.log("success");
        } else {
          console.log("issue");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error",err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: That's a *path* parameter, why are you trying to supply it as a *query* parameter? Just put it in the URL, `\`${apiEndPoint}/${this.state.userId}\``.

Comment: thanks sir! I'm a newbie and wasn't aware with the term "Path parameter" .. I fixed the issue and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working example for **Path Parameter Axios PUT request** -

```
saveDetails = async () => {
    const { username, password, userid } = this.state;
    axios
      .put(apiEndPoint+"updateUser/"+userid, {
        username:username,
        password:password,
      })
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          console.log("done");
          
        } else {
          console.log("error");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error",err);
      });
  };
```